# Jquery Ajax calls fail after first call success?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm build jquery to build a custom email system (left pane list of messages - right pane the selected or current message) ....

After an Ajax call is made (for example - the message is deleted and the left pane is reloaded using **.load** to update the list), calls from there fails from there (its as if the reloaded content doesnt see the ajax on the page anymore... and nothing happens)

Below is an example of the jquery that deletes the mail. The deleteMail script also echos the updated list..

$('#leftmail').html(loading).load('/pages/mail/async/deleteMail.php',{'id' : id });

Does anyone have any ideas why this would happen? It is a .load things specifically?

Please help! Thanks!

F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding events to elements only happens once. When you load the pane via AJAX, those events are lost and not recreated on the newly fetched elements.

The jQuery [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function is designed for this. Instead of `$('element').click(function() {})`, you'd do `$('element').live('click', function() {})` to have those click events work on content loaded after the initial `domready` event.

Comment: Hm...interesting.. but I've added this and there is no change..?

Comment: $('#mailselect').live('change', function() {
  
  var mailbox = $("#mailselect").val();
  if (mailbox != "")
  {
   //alert("Move to " + mailbox); 
   
   var valArray = $('input:checkbox').serializeArray(); 
   $('#leftmail').html(loading).load('<?php echo $cfg->wwwroot?>/pages/mail/async/moveMail.php',{'id' : mailbox,"checkboxs":valArray, "view":'<?php echo $view?>'});
   
   
  }
  
  
  
  })

Comment: Wait, actually nevermind... I'm an idiot...I was adding the live to the completely wrong event...D'oh!